# Quadratic Form (quad_form) over Expressions in CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, convex

I am building risk term in a quadratic optimization problem (QP) using CVXPY and I'm struggling to combine expressions with a covariance matrix using `quad_form`.

```
from cvxpy import Variable, quad_form
from numpy import identity
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

assets = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
optimal = Series(1 / 4, assets)
covariances = DataFrame(identity(4) * 0.20, index=assets, columns=assets)
covariances.iloc[2, 3] += 0.01
covariances.iloc[3, 2] = covariances.iloc[2, 3]

target = Series([Variable(name=asset) for asset in assets], index=assets)
difference = target - optimal

active_variance = quad_form(difference.values, covariances.values)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I can just do the calculation in Pandas, but then CVXPY does not know the expression is convex.

```
active_variance = difference.T.dot(covariances).dot(difference)
print(active_variance.curvature)
```

This problem is related to my [earlier question with docplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65555695/error-passing-a-linear-expression-to-a-quadratic-form-in-docplex/65560903#65560903) though the solution there doesn't work here as docplex does not require the problem be convex but CVXPY does.  Is there a correct form in CVXPY?

Comment: The usage of `quad_form` here makes only sense iff `difference` would be a vector of decision variables (or constants). Due to your usage of pandas (i'm not sure if intended or not) here, `difference` **is becoming non-numeric / dtype=object which can never be used within cvxpy**. Hint: `AAA + -0.25`. In general, i would not recommend mixing pandas and cvxpy without knowing a lot about all the internals: hidden casts and co.

Comment: OK, this is a bit sad because the larger optimization is pretty complicated without Pandas keeping track of the data alignment, but that appears to be what is required.  Thanks.